# Best way to create a Android XMPP chat client in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, xmpp, chat, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a iOS and Android XMPP chat client using Unity/C#/Mono. I got a fully functional chat client working for iOS using Jabber.net, but it does not work for Android. So does anyone have any idea of a library that works with Unity/C# for Android?

This post discusses Android and XMPP solutions, but have not found any way of connecting this to Unity:
[Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)

This is my question related to getting Jabber.net working for Android with Unity:
[Jabber.net on Unity/Android error (No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libc.so, skipping init)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156312/jabber-net-on-unity-android-error-no-jni-onload-found-in-system-lib-libc-so-s)

Comment: i have complied the jabber-net library for mono 2.0. but when i run it in device i am getting this exception.
'ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method'
How did you resolve it ?

Comment: Don't remember. Could it be related to stripping level or C# version? http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/43038-ExecutionEngineException-Attempting-to-JIT-compile-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody have answered here I how I solved it:

1. ASmack for Android in a new Android project in eclipse
2. Build a custom wrapper for ASmack with the basic public methods for login,logout,send messages et.c.
3. Extract as jar library.
4. Import jar into Unity3D
5. Use Unity3D's AndroidJNI methods to call the public methods of the jar
6. Callbacks are set inside the Java-wrapper and call with "UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage()" (classes.jar from Unity app package have to be imported into Eclipse project to compile)
7. Success!

A bit work is required and takes some time to debug and build, but it does work.

Comment: Sorry, the video is unavailable.

Comment: Sorry to hear that (it was not my video). Removed the link. Hopefully my instructions will be of help.

Comment: And what about iOS client? As far as I know ASmack won't run on iOS.

Comment: As mentioned in the question we used Jabber.net for iOS. Note that this question was posted 2012, not sure what's the best option today.

Comment: Hello @Sunkas, I am making XMPP plugins, can you please help to show some flow or else you can share your code , thanks

Comment: can you please help me sort out this issue if you faced while you create Plugins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893076/smackinitialization-could-not-determine-smack-version

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all this manipulation with ASmack I recommend to use [MatriX XMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/). We are using this library for our Unity projects.

And it works on Win, Mac, iOS, Android without any special manipulation. We have only 1 problem with this lib - can't make it work on in WebPlayer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a long time since I asked this question. I remembered that I emailed MatriX at the time with a few questions and at the time we could not use it since it lacked some requirement. Can't unfortunately remember what.

Comment: @Sunkas 2 years ago, AFAIK, there was problem with Sockets and Pro license in Unity )

Comment: Is this still working for you? I've been trying to get it running on Android and I get errors about System.EntryPointNotFoundException: getifaddrs

Comment: @AlejandroHuerta I can say that it works in stand alone build for sure. I will test it on Android and iOS tomorrow.

Comment: @Suvitruf thank you. I'm also using it successfully on on standalone but have had no success with Android. I haven't tested iOS yet.

Comment: @AlejandroHuerta I've tested Matrix on iOS. It works. Will try Android later.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Suvitruf sorry to bother you, did you ever get a chance to test on Android?

Comment: @Suvitruf do you have any special configuration set? Android version? I've been trying and failing to get sockets working on the few phones i have to test on and have had to resort to using the BOSH transport layer.

Comment: @AlejandroHuerta nop. But our game only for 5.0+ Android. So, I don't know does it works on older devices.

Comment: @Suvitruf I started messing with player settings, the min API level doesn't seem to affect it BUT it seems the problem comes from using Api Compatibility Level .net 2.0 (Not the subset). I can at least progress from here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlejandroHuerta I am also getting same issue as you suggested in comment, Build running in Unity Editor very well but fails in Android Device with error log : `getifaddrs`. 
If you have any solution then please help me. Thanks

Comment: @technerd I never figured out a fix for this issue. I spoke with the devs and they insisted it was an issue on my end. I believe it had something to do with the android version I was running but I'm not longer working on that project so I haven't looked into it recently.